# Got an Australian ETA unaware of a misdemeanor at the time

Tags: us-citizens, australia, criminal-records

I'm due to travel to Australia in 2 weeks, and I answered no on the ETA regarding criminal convictions. I got my FBI background back (was planning on applying for the onshore travel visa once I got there for more time), and saw I had a misdemeanor record with a $250 fine, no jail time. There was this situation 20 years ago that my dad's attorney took care of, and I wasn't aware it gave me a record, as I had to apply for security clearances before, and this never came up. I spoke to an immigration attorney in Australia who said I should fill out a form 1023 and disclose this on the IPC. In researching this, I find answers to be conflicting, as some state no was the appropriate answer for an ETA, as they are concerned about jail time for 12 months or more, and others state a more strict version of it. I plan on disclosing it on my IPC and provide them with them the Form 1023, but my concern is being turned away at the border. Besides the wasted trip, there would be the devastation of not being able to see my partner. Has anyone had similar no yes experiences with the ETA and how did it turn out?

Comment: "I had to apply for security clearances before, and this never came up. " It may very well have come up, but as it was resolved, and apparently considered a minor matter, it didn't count against you in getting clearances.

Answer (score 1):

If the ETA was already granted, and a formal security clearance process in the US couldn't dig it up, it's **very unlikely** this would somehow come up when landing in Australia. This goes double these days when most people (including US passport holders) can use the automated gates that require zero interaction with a human, meaning that you will be let in as long as your
passport & biometrics check out.

Declaring it preemptively by filling out the form would be the "right" thing to do, which is why your lawyer is telling you to do so, but it just sounds like a bureaucratic nightmare that would be far more likely to jeopardize your chances of being able to visit. YMMV.